# What is the meaning of "as" in "as will happen if there is a short-circuit"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "as" in the following sentences,

> A synchronous motor is an AC motor in which the speed of the motor is
> proportional to the frequency of the electric power.  When the power
> fails, ***as*** will happen if there is a short-circuit, the inertia
> of the mechanical load on the motor will continue rotating the motor.
> The motor will then act as a generator supplying current, and this
> will contribute to the total current flowing to the fault.

?
(Source :  Fault Current Calculations  BY BRIAN MCFADDEN )

Does "When the power fails, as will happen if there is a short-circuit" mean "When the power fails, if there is a short-circuit will happen" ?

Does "as" mean "if there is a short-circuit" ?

If so, can you provide links or sites that explain this kind of grammatical situation in an easy and rich way with many examples?

Comment: In the quoted sentence, **as** can be replaced by **which** without changing the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

> When the power fails, as will happen if there is a short-circuit, the inertia of the mechanical load on the motor will continue rotating the motor.

Has the same meaning as:

> When the power fails, the inertia of the mechanical load on the motor will continue rotating the motor. A short-circuit will cause the power to fail.

More generally a statement of the form

> When X, as happens if Y, then Z.

means that when X occurs, Z will follow, and also that Y is a likely cause of or reason for X.

"as happens if" can be read as "which can be caused by" but is usually used only for the most likely or at least a particularly common cause.